# Where does the code need to be when working with a UserForm in Word?

Tags: vba, ms-word

I've been working in Word with a UserForm to populate some tables within the document. But I'm very confused about where the code is supposed to be written. In the attached image, I've circled the two locations where it can be. But what I've noticed is that it cannot be in only one or the other, it has to have at lease some parts in both of those locations. What determines which blocks need to go where? I know it works if both locations have identical scripts, but I don't want something that "just works" without explanation; I want to know the actual rule that is in place to do this correctly. Thanks in advance!

Edit: This form opens via a button in the doc. Once the form is completed, a button within the form is used to populate the doc tables with the form's fields.

[image]

Comment: The entire code may be located in UserForm module. No necessity to put it into ThisDocument module unless you need to handle Document or Application events.

Comment: @omegastripes I apologize; I just added a description of the process flow. Hopefully this makes it clearer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ThisDocument module - code for the click event of the button in the document.

vaultValuesForm - code for the click event of the button on the UserForm.

The simple way to determine where the code needs to be is to right click the button you need to write code for and select "View Code". A skeleton routine is then created for you in the correct module.